# How to quickly edit HTML using Harp

Tags: automation, harp

Currently, I am editing the layout and contents of my page on the fly using developer tools in chrome.

Is there any way to do the same thing without having to recompile harp each and every single time (perhaps I am misunderstanding how harp works).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sound like you might be misunderstanding a bit, yes. You can run `harp server` to serve your current project at `http://localhost:9000`. Then, any changes you make to the layout or metadata will be recompiled whenever you refresh.

Harp automatically recompiles whenever a new request comes in for that asset, which keeps it fast, and also means you don’t have to manually recompile the site. The `harp compile` command is more if you are ready to publish the static HTML, CSS, and JavaScript somewhere (ex. Surge.sh or Apache Cordova/PhoneGap app).

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JWU70PWVVbc) is a bit out of date but covers the basics and might be helpful. My post on [starting a blog with Harp](http://kennethormandy.com/journal/start-a-blog-with-harp) also covers some basics.

Comment: Ok great, thanks Kenneth. The work that you're doing up in Vancouver with Chloi is amazing by the way, keep it up :)